# Inheritance Mapping with Fluent NHibernate

Tags: nhibernate, mapping, types, fluent, polymorphism

Given the following scenario, I want map the type hierarchy to the database schema using Fluent NHibernate.

I am using NHibernate 2.0

---

**Type Hierarchy**

```
public abstract class Item
{
    public virtual int ItemId { get; set; }
    public virtual string ItemType { get; set; }
    public virtual string FieldA { get; set; }
}

public abstract class SubItem : Item
{
    public virtual string FieldB { get; set; } 
}

public class ConcreteItemX : SubItem
{
    public virtual string FieldC { get; set; } 
}

public class ConcreteItemY : Item
{
    public virtual string FieldD { get; set; }
}
```

[See image](http://www.freeimagehosting.net/uploads/3e9efc1fee.png)

The `Item` and `SubItem` classes are abstract.

---

**Database Schema**

```
+----------+  +---------------+  +---------------+
| Item     |  | ConcreteItemX |  | ConcreteItemY |
+==========+  +===============+  +===============+
| ItemId   |  | ItemId        |  | ItemId        |
| ItemType |  | FieldC        |  | FieldD        |
| FieldA   |  +---------------+  +---------------+
| FieldB   |
+----------+
```

[See image](http://www.freeimagehosting.net/uploads/10644fe741.png)

The `ItemType` field determines the concrete type.

Each record in the `ConcreteItemX` table has a single corresponding record in the `Item` table; likewise for the `ConcreteItemY` table.

`FieldB` is always null if the item type is `ConcreteItemY`.

---

**The Mapping (so far)**

```
public class ItemMap : ClassMap<Item>
{
    public ItemMap()
    {
        WithTable("Item");
        Id(x => x.ItemId, "ItemId");
        Map(x => x.FieldA, "FieldA");

        JoinedSubClass<ConcreteItemX>("ItemId", MapConcreteItemX);
        JoinedSubClass<ConcreteItemY>("ItemId", MapConcreteItemY);
    }

    private static void MapConcreteItemX(JoinedSubClassPart<ConcreteItemX> part)
    {
        part.WithTableName("ConcreteItemX");
        part.Map(x => x.FieldC, "FieldC");
    }

    private static void MapConcreteItemY(JoinedSubClassPart<ConcreteItemY> part)
    {
        part.WithTableName("ConcreteItemX");
        part.Map(x => x.FieldD, "FieldD");
    }
}
```

`FieldB` is not mapped.

---

**The Question**

How do I map the `FieldB` property of the `SubItem` class using Fluent NHibernate?

Is there any way I can leverage `DiscriminateSubClassesOnColumn` using the `ItemType` field?

---

**Addendum**

I am able to achieve the desired result using an hbm.xml file:

```
<class name="Item" table="Item">

  <id name="ItemId" type="Int32" column="ItemId">
    <generator class="native"/>
  </id>

  <discriminator column="ItemType" type="string"/>

  <property name="FieldA" column="FieldA"/>

  <subclass name="ConcreteItemX" discriminator-value="ConcreteItemX">
    <!-- Note the FieldB mapping here -->
    <property name="FieldB" column="FieldB"/>
    <join table="ConcreteItemX">
      <key column="ItemId"/>
      <property name="FieldC" column="FieldC"/>
    </join>
  </subclass>

  <subclass name="ConcreteItemY" discriminator-value="ConcreteItemY">
    <join table="ConcreteItemY">
      <key column="ItemId"/>
      <property name="FieldD" column="FieldD"/>
    </join>
  </subclass>

</class>
```

How do I accomplish the above mapping using Fluent NHibernate?

Is it possible to mix table-per-class-hierarchy with table-per-subclass using Fluent NHibernate?

Comment: Any reason this is marked community wiki? In any case, could you clarify the mapping strategy you are using? JoinedSubClassPart implies the table-per-subclass pattern but saying concrete items are persisted to the Item table implies the table-per-class-hierarchy pattern.

Comment: I'm not sure how to change the community wiki setting.

Ignoring FieldB, I can use table-per-subclass. The presence of FieldB causes me some confusion. It seems to be a mixture of the two strategies. The ConcreteItemX type inherits FieldB from SubItem. FieldB is persisted in the Item table.

Answer (score 27):

I know this is really old, but it is now pretty simple to set up fluent to generate the exact mapping you initially desired.  Since I came across this post when searching for the answer, I thought I'd post it.

You just create your ClassMap for the base class without any reference to your subclasses:

```
public class ItemMap : ClassMap<Item>
{
    public ItemMap()
    {
        this.Table("Item");
        this.DiscriminateSubClassesOnColumn("ItemType");
        this.Id(x => x.ItemId, "ItemId");
        this.Map(x => x.FieldA, "FieldA");
    }
}
```

Then map your abstract subclass like this:

```
public class SubItemMap: SubclassMap<SubItemMap>
{
    public SubItemMap()
    {
        this.Map(x => x.FieldB);
    }
}
```

Then map your concrete subclasses like so:

```
public class ConcreteItemXMap : SubclassMap<ConcreteItemX>
{
    public ConcretItemXMap()
    {
        this.Join("ConcreteItemX", x =>
        {
            x.KeyColumn("ItemID");
            x.Map("FieldC")
        });
    }
}
```

Hopefully this helps somebody else looking for this type of mapping with fluent.

Comment: Nice! Exactly what I needed.

Answer (score 1):

Well, I'm not sure that it's quite right, but it might work... If anyone can do this more cleanly, I'd love to see it (seriously, I would; this is an interesting problem).

Using the exact class definitions you gave, here are the mappings:

```
public class ItemMap : ClassMap<Item>
{
    public ItemMap()
    {
        Id(x => x.ItemId);
        Map(x => x.ItemType);
        Map(x => x.FieldA);

        AddPart(new ConcreteItemYMap());
    }
}

public class SubItemMap : ClassMap<SubItem>
{
    public SubItemMap()
    {
        WithTable("Item");

        // Get the base map and "inherit" the mapping parts
        ItemMap baseMap = new ItemMap();
        foreach (IMappingPart part in baseMap.Parts)
        {
            // Skip any sub class parts... yes this is ugly
            // Side note to anyone reading this that might know:
            // Can you use GetType().IsSubClassOf($GenericClass$)
            // without actually specifying the generic argument such
            // that it will return true for all subclasses, regardless
            // of the generic type?
            if (part.GetType().BaseType.Name == "JoinedSubClassPart`1")
                continue;
            AddPart(part);
        }
        Map(x => x.FieldB);
        AddPart(new ConcreteItemXMap());
    }
}

public class ConcreteItemXMap : JoinedSubClassPart<ConcreteItemX>
{
    public ConcreteItemXMap()
        : base("ItemId")
    {
        WithTableName("ConcreteItemX");
        Map(x => x.FieldC);
    }
}

public class ConcreteItemYMap : JoinedSubClassPart<ConcreteItemY>
{
    public ConcreteItemYMap()
        : base("ItemId")
    {
        WithTableName("ConcreteItemY");
        Map(x => x.FieldD);
    }
}
```

Those mappings produce two hbm.xml files like so (some extraneous data removed for clarity):

```
  <class name="Item" table="`Item`">
    <id name="ItemId" column="ItemId" type="Int32">
      <generator class="identity" />
    </id>
    <property name="FieldA" type="String">
      <column name="FieldA" />
    </property>
    <property name="ItemType" type="String">
      <column name="ItemType" />
    </property>
    <joined-subclass name="ConcreteItemY" table="ConcreteItemY">
      <key column="ItemId" />
      <property name="FieldD">
        <column name="FieldD" />
      </property>
    </joined-subclass>
  </class>

  <class name="SubItem" table="Item">
    <id name="ItemId" column="ItemId" type="Int32">
      <generator class="identity" />
    </id>
    <property name="FieldB" type="String">
      <column name="FieldB" />
    </property>
    <property name="ItemType" type="String">
      <column name="ItemType" />
    </property>
    <property name="FieldA" type="String">
      <column name="FieldA" />
    </property>
    <joined-subclass name="ConcreteItemX" table="ConcreteItemX">
      <key column="ItemId" />
      <property name="FieldC">
        <column name="FieldC" />
      </property>
    </joined-subclass>
  </class>
```

It's ugly, but it looks like it might generate a usable mapping file and it's Fluent! :/
You might be able to tweak the idea some more to get exactly what you want.

Answer (score 1):

The line of code: `if (part.GetType().BaseType.Name == "JoinedSubClassPart1")`
can be rewritten as follows:

```
part.GetType().BaseType.IsGenericType && part.GetType().BaseType.GetGenericTypeDefinition() == typeof(JoinedSubClassPart<>)
```

Answer (score 1):

This is how I resolved my inheritance problem:

```
public static class DataObjectBaseExtension
{
    public static void DefaultMap<T>(this ClassMap<T> DDL) where T : IUserAuditable 
    {
        DDL.Map(p => p.AddedUser).Column("AddedUser");
        DDL.Map(p => p.UpdatedUser).Column("UpdatedUser");
    }
}
```

You can then add this to your superclass map constructor:

```
internal class PatientMap : ClassMap<Patient>
{
    public PatientMap()
    {
        Id(p => p.GUID).Column("GUID");
        Map(p => p.LocalIdentifier).Not.Nullable();
        Map(p => p.DateOfBirth).Not.Nullable();
        References(p => p.Sex).Column("RVSexGUID");
        References(p => p.Ethnicity).Column("RVEthnicityGUID");

        this.DefaultMap();
    }


}
```