# Fluent NHibernate one-to-one mapping with synthetic keys

Tags: c#, nhibernate, fluent-nhibernate

I have two tables

```
tblPart
(
    partId,
    subpartId UNIQUE NULL
)

tblSubpart
(
    subpartId
)
```

So I can only have zero or one subPart associated with the part at the same time.

I'm trying to map this as

```
ClassMap<Part>
{
    HasOne(x=>x.Subpart);
}
```

and the convention rewrites the foreign key so it uses subpartId instead of partId.

however generated query ads

```
subpart.partId
```

into the query, which does not exist.

What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 0):

Why not use inheritance?

Check out this question

[Inheritance Mapping with Fluent NHibernate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/655494/inheritance-mapping-with-fluent-nhibernate)

And this page (search inheritance to jump to the right section)

http://wiki.fluentnhibernate.org/Fluent_mapping

Comment: The schema was simplified to show the keys and such. In reality two objects have a different relationship, which should not be expressed as subclasses.