# Ignore Base class with Sharp Architecture and Fluent NHibernate

Tags: nhibernate, inheritance, fluent-nhibernate, sharp-architecture

Using Sharp Architecture 1.9

I have a base class that inherits from the Sharp Arch Entity class

```
public class LineItem : EntityWithTypedId<Guid>
{
  // various properties
}
```

and then two classes that inherit:

```
public class BasketItem : LineItem { public virtual Basket Basket; ...}
public class OrderItem : LineItem { public virtual Order Order ...}
```

In my database I have two tables. BasketItems and OrderItems.

My problem: Fluent NHibernate (AutoMapping) is trying to map LineItem.

My question: How do I tell NHibernate to ignore the LineItem mapping given that I still want to map the EntityWithTypedId property to the BasketItems and OrderItems table?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution was to add code like this to my automap configuration:

```
AutoMap.AssemblyOf<Entity>(cfg)
  .IgnoreBase<Entity>();
```

More info [here](http://wiki.fluentnhibernate.org/Auto_mapping#Inheritance).

Comment: Matt the link is no longer valid, but I would like to see what you did.

Answer (score 0):

it depends on what the table structure of the basketitem and orderitem are. Are you using the table per concrete class or table per class hierarchy?

[Inheritance Mapping with Fluent NHibernate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/655494/inheritance-mapping-with-fluent-nhibernate)

Comment: I'm using table per class hierachy