# Fluent NHibernate - Query over a derived class

Tags: c#, fluent-nhibernate

Lets say I have two classes:

```
public class A
{
  public virtual int Id { get; set; }
  public virtual Object1 Obj { get; set; }
}

public class B : A
{
  public new virtual Object2 Obj { get; set; }
}
```

I use Fluent NHibernate and I have created two different mappings for the two classes. However, when I try to query class A in my repository, FNH finds both class B and A, which kind of makes sense since both are A.

Example (this criteria will query over both A and B):

```
public List<T> GetByName(string name)
{
  return Session.CreateCriteriaOf<A>.Add(Restrictions...);
}
```

When writing `CreateCriteriaOf<A>`, I only want to query over A - not B. How can I solve my problem?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you better make an inheritance tree where both A and B derive from a common (abstract) base type. Then NHibernate can make the distinction by a [discriminator column](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/655494/inheritance-mapping-with-fluent-nhibernate).

Of course, your data model should accommodate this, so I hope your model is not prescribed in any way.